# How to import meetings into office365 (EWS and Powershell?)

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, impersonation

I need assistance importing bookings/meetings into office365. I can export the booking information from our old web-based system into csv, but need a way to import into exchange in office365.

The most promising method I have found is using Exchange Web Services to connect to the cloud with powershell an then use impersonation to re-reate the bookings as the appropriate users against the newly created room mailboxes. But I am open to other suggestions if there is a better way.

The problem I have currently with EWS and powershell (like this: http://mikepfeiffer.net/2011/01/creating-calendar-items-with-powershell-and-the-ews-managed-api/) is that when I try to connect I get Autodiscover errors. Is this still possible using office 365?

Update: 
Hi Glen Scales,

Thank you kindly for your example, looks promising, but I am still getting a autodiscover error when I run your code above, specific error(s) and description of what I am doing step by step below. I am hoping I am doing something obviously wrong and you will be able to correct me

I am running powershell and connecting to o365 with our credentials like this:

```
$loginUserName = "admin@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "secret" –AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $loginUserName, $PWord
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential
```

Then loading your function and trying a test command like this:

```
$Start = Get-Date
$End = (Get-Date).AddHours(1)

Create-Appointment -MailboxName mymailbox@domain.com -Subject "Test appointment" -Start $Start -End $End -Body "Test Body" -Credentials $Credential -Location "sdfkjhsdfjh"
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "AutodiscoverUrl" with "2" argument(s): "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located."
At \\blahblah\bookings.ps1:100 char:3
+         $service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AutodiscoverLocalException

Using CAS Server : 
Exception calling "Bind" with "2" argument(s): "The Url property on the ExchangeService object must be set."
At \\blahblah\bookings.ps1:114 char:3
+         $Calendar = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folde ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceLocalException

Exception calling "Save" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: destinationFolderId"
At \\blahblah\bookings.ps1:127 char:3
+         $Appointment.Save($Calendar.Id,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvita ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you use credentials in Office365 or you will get an Autodiscover error eg something like this should work

```html
####################### 
<# 
.SYNOPSIS 
 Create an Appointment from Commandline using Powershell and the Exchange Web Services API in a Mailbox in Exchange Online 
 
.DESCRIPTION 
  Create an Appointment from Commandline using Powershell and the Exchange Web Services API in a Mailbox in Exchange Online 
 
 Requires the EWS Managed API from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951

.EXAMPLE
 PS C:\>Create-Appointment  -MailboxName user.name@domain.com -Subject AppointmentName -Start (Get-Date) -End (Get-Date).AddHours(1) -Body "Test Body" -Credential (Get-Credential) -Location "Coffee Shop"

 This Example creates an appointment in a Mailboxes Calendar folder
#> 
function Create-Appointment 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param( 
     [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
   [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Subject,
  [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [DateTime]$Start,
  [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)] [DateTime]$End,
  [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Location,
  [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Body,
  [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$true)] [PSCredential]$Credentials
    )  
  Begin
   {
  ## Load Managed API dll  
  ###CHECK FOR EWS MANAGED API, IF PRESENT IMPORT THE HIGHEST VERSION EWS DLL, ELSE EXIT
  $EWSDLL = (($(Get-ItemProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path Registry::$(Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services'|Sort-Object Name -Descending| Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name)).'Install Directory') + "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
  if (Test-Path $EWSDLL)
      {
      Import-Module $EWSDLL
      }
  else
      {
      "$(get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss):"
      "This script requires the EWS Managed API 1.2 or later."
      "Please download and install the current version of the EWS Managed API from"
      "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255472"
      ""
      "Exiting Script."
      exit
      } 
  
  ## Set Exchange Version  
  $ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2  
    
  ## Create Exchange Service Object  
  $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)  
    
  ## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials  
    
  #Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account  
  #$psCred = Get-Credential  
  $creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Credentials.UserName.ToString(),$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString())  
  $service.Credentials = $creds      
  #Credentials Option 2  
  #service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  
    
  ## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates  
    
  ## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
  ## Create a compilation environment
  $Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
  $Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
  $Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
  $Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
  $Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
  $Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
  $Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() { 
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@ 
  $TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
  $TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

  ## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
  $TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
  [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

  ## end code from http://poshcode.org/624
    
  ## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use  
    
  #CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover  
  $service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  
  "Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url   
     
  #CAS URL Option 2 Hardcoded  
    
  #$uri=[system.URI] "https://casservername/ews/exchange.asmx"  
  #$service.Url = $uri    
    
  ## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation  
    
  #$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName) 

  # Bind to the Calendar Folder
  $folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar,$MailboxName)   
  $Calendar = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
  $Appointment = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment -ArgumentList $service  
  #Set Start Time  
  $Appointment.Start = $Start 
  #Set End Time  
  $Appointment.End = $End
  #Set Subject  
  $Appointment.Subject = $Subject
  #Set the Location  
  $Appointment.Location = $Location
  #Set any Notes  
  $Appointment.Body = $Body
  #Create Appointment will save to the default Calendar  
  $Appointment.Save($Calendar.Id,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvitationsMode]::SendToNone)  

 }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Glen Scales, Thank you for your answer, I have edited my question to add more details.

Comment: Does the user $loginUserName = "admin@domain.onmicrosoft.com" have a Mailbox ? eg can you logon to OWA with this account. The example I gave is just using delegation so it would mean that admin@domain.onmicrosoft.com would need rights to the Mailbox mymailbox@domain.com . Also does mymailbox@domain.com actually exist in the cloud ?

Comment: You can also try bypassing Autodiscover by replacing the line

$service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  

with 

$uri=[system.URI] "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"  
$service.Url = $uri

Comment: Hi Glen, Your code has been a great help thank you. The autodiscover issue turned out to be proxy server causing trouble. Now moving on to solve problems with time zone error at 
        $appointment.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SendInvitationsMode]::SendToAllAndSaveCopy)

Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to convert 2009-01-01T00:00:00.000 from (UTC+08:00) Perth to UTC."

Comment: For anyone watching, fixed with this:
    $standardDisplayName = "(GMT+08:00) PPerth"
    $standardName = "My Perth"
    $baseUtcOffset = New-TimeSpan -Hours 8
    $daylightDisplayName=[string]::Empty
    $adjustmentRules=$null
    $disableDaylightSavingTime=$false
    $TZ = [TimeZoneInfo]::CreateCustomTimeZone($standardName, $baseUtcOffset, $standardDisplayName, $standardName,$daylightDisplayName,$adjustmentRules,$disableDaylightSavingTime)

    $appointment.StartTimeZone = $TZ
    $appointment.EndTimeZone = $TZ